# Iterates a list lst and applies the function f to each link to create a “fresh” list

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void    *content;
    void    content_size;
    struct s_list    *next;
}   t_list;
```

And I'm trying to create a function:

```
t_list *lstmap(t_list *lst, t_list *(*f)(t_list *elem));
```

that iterates through each element of the *t_list* '*lst*', apply the function '*f*' to each element and returns a new *t_list* with the fresh elements.

At first, I tried the following approach:

```
tmp = f(lst);
first = tmp;
while(lst)
{
    tmp = f(lst);
    tmp = tmp->next;
    lst = lst->next;
}
```

which did not work.

Then, when iterating like this:

```
tmp = f(lst);
first = tmp;
while (lst->next)
{
    tmp->next = f(lst->next);
    tmp = tmp->next;
    lst = lst->next;
}
```

It worked.

Why they differ in result?

Comment: A fresh list needs fresh nodes pointing to fresh content. These must occupy some kind of memory. Where does this memory come from?

Comment: Also the common general name of this function is [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: Answer depends on you f() and also on the fact, if you plan to return a new copy of list or modify an existing one.

Comment: defining the `next` attribute of your struct as `void *` seems counter-intuitive - shouldn't it be a `struct s_list *` or `t_list *`?

Comment: @n.m. f returns a new element.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I mispelled it, thanks!

Comment: @dbrank0 I want to return a new copy of the list. f function is supposed to return a new node I believe.

Comment: I imagine that `content_size` is of some integral type rather than `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first loop, you never assign anything to `tmp->next`, so the result list never gets built. Also, the assignment `tmp = f(lst);` overwrites the result of `tmp = tmp->next;` from the previous iteration (which likely isn't well-defined/initialized).

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = f(lst);
first = tmp;
while(lst)
{
    tmp = f(lst);
    ...
```

You assign a value to `tmp` and then immediately assign another value to `tmp`. The first assignment thus has no effect, except the value is also saved in `first`. So this fragment is equivalent to

```
 first = f(lst);
 while(lst)
 {
      tmp = f(lst);
      ....
```

But `first` is then not linked to any other item. In fact no item is linked to any other item. So the entire loop has no effect except creating and forgetting some nodes, and thus leaking memory.